# the model in view could not bind to the action in the controller in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have defined the custom name about the input tag in Index view of Account. The name is `iptloginPassWord` and `iptloginPassWord`.  However, in the controller the model will be `null` whenever the submit button is clicked.

I have attached the code below.  Is this a model binding issue?  Could you guys help to determine what is wrong here?

**View:**

```
<div class="rl-modal-body">
    <div class="login-model-body-wrap">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
        {
            <div class="rlf-model-group">
                <div class="ipt-container">
                    <div class="ipt-config ipt-UserName"></div>
                    @*h5提供了required属性,Name的N必须为大写*@
                    @*<input id="iptloginUserName" type="text" name="iptloginUserName" value="" placeholder="请输入用户名" class="ipt ipt-login" required="required" />*@
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @id = "iptloginUserName", @Name = "iptloginUserName", @placeholder = "请输入用户名", @class = "ipt ipt-login", @required = "required" })
                </div>
                <p class="rl-p"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="rlf-model-group">
                <div class="ipt-container">
                    <div class="ipt-config ipt-Password"></div>
                    @*<input id="iptloginPassWord" type="password" name="iptloginPassWord" value="" placeholder="请输入密码" class="ipt ipt-login ipt-passwordforJS" required="required" />*@
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @id = "iptloginPassWord", @Name = "iptloginPassWord", @placeholder = "请输入密码", @class = "ipt ipt-login ipt-passwordforJS", @required = "required" })
                </div>
                <p class="rl-p"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="rlf-model-group">
                <label for="AutoLogin">
                    <input id="AutoLogin" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />自动登录
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="rlf-model-group">
                <p class="rl-p"></p>
                <input id="iptloginsubmit" type="submit" name="Button" value="登录" class="btn-red btn-full" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Controller:**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Account/

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Logon(User model)
    {
        string username = model.UserName;//this will get null 
        string password = model.Password;//this will also get null
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the id and name attribute have to be `iptloginPassWord`?

Comment: Yes,correct.The razor view has two input tags. Both iptloginPassWord and iptloginUserName have to be ID and Name.

Comment: have you added @model User at the top of the view?

Comment: yes,I added the @model user in the top of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Custom ModelBinder?

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string username = request.Form.Get("iptloginUserName");
        string password = request.Form.Get("iptloginPassWord");

        return new User
                   {
                       UserName = title,
                       Password = password
                   };
    }
}
```

You then need to inform the controller action of the new ModelBinder

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))] User home)
    {
        //use model here 
        return View();
    }
```

More information: http://codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Answer (score 3):

When you do this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
```

The `id` and `name` attribute of the user name textbox will be set to `UserName` automatically, and that's what makes the value of `model.UserName` in the controller post method the same as the value of the user name textbox.

I'm not sure why you change the `id` and `name` attribute of the user name textbox to `iptloginUserName`, but if you remove the `id` and `name` attribute from this syntax

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @id = "iptloginUserName", @Name = "iptloginUserName", @placeholder = "请输入用户名", @class = "ipt ipt-login", @required = "required" })
```

and change it to this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @placeholder = "请输入用户名", @class = "ipt ipt-login", @required = "required" })
```

`model.UserName` won't be null in your controller post method and it will contain the value entered in the user name textbox.

The same thing applies to the password textbox, so change this syntax

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @id = "iptloginPassWord", @Name = "iptloginPassWord", @placeholder = "请输入密码", @class = "ipt ipt-login ipt-passwordforJS", @required = "required" })
```

to this

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @placeholder = "请输入密码", @class = "ipt ipt-login ipt-passwordforJS", @required = "required" })
```

Comment: Yes,you are correct. The default model binding will use the name of the model to set the name of input tag.But if I want to do a custom model binding to use the custom name in the input tag, could you help to figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom ids then uncomment the following lines from view

```
@*<input id="iptloginUserName" type="text" name="iptloginUserName" value="" placeholder="请输入用户名" class="ipt ipt-login" required="required" />*@

@*<input id="iptloginPassWord" type="password" name="iptloginPassWord" value="" placeholder="请输入密码" class="ipt ipt-login ipt-passwordforJS" required="required" />*@
```

And update method headers

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logon(User model, string iptloginUserName, string iptloginPassWord)
{
    model.UserName= iptloginUserName;
    model.Password = iptloginPassWord;

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: But i think Html helper method is the same as the Html tag.